# Thermal relativity

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity

The more energy we add (heat) to a substance, say water, the higher Kinetic energy its particles have. Since the Kinetic energy is linked to the time taken by particles to move a certain distance and taking time dilation equation into account, the speed of particles will appear smaller to an observer, i.e he would find it cool instead of hot. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi adi, you have to say which observer you mean. The observer in a fast spaceship will see everything as normal inside, it is an observer moving at a different speed to the first one that sees the effect of relatively on the first observers surroundings.

Comment: asabs? what do you mean @Countto10.  Also, OP please clarify and make qn clearer

Comment: I think you mix up different concept here.  Heat does not accelerate the body . It goes into internal energy . Time dilation for the heated up block is compensate by length contraction of the body.  The only difference upon heating that body is in the term rest mass time c. The warmed up body is more massive.

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter stated, the speed of particles will depend on the observer.  If the bulk substance and the observer are in the same inertial frame, the moving particles' internal clocks will run slow relative to the observer, but the observer can correctly measure their speeds.

### relativity and internal energy

The internal energy of a substance which is related to temperature comes from the motion of the particles that make up the substance.  As you add heat to the substance the particles will jiggle around faster.

If the particles are moving so fast that special relativistic effects start to matter, the simple $E_\mathrm{k}=\frac{1}{2} m v^2$ picture of kinetic energy is incorrect.  For non-interacting, monatomic particles in an ideal gas the relativistic energy of a particle is $E_\mathrm{tot}=\gamma m c^2$, where $\gamma$ is the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor):

$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$$

The kinetic energy of a particle would be:

$$ E_\mathrm{k} = E_\mathrm{tot} - E_\mathrm{mass} = (\gamma-1)m c^2$$

For real substances there could be interaction energies or other kinetic energies like rotational or internal molecular vibrations that also contribute to the total internal energy and change this a bit.